# When first masonry 'item' is hidden all remaining items form into a single column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, masonry

I'm trying to use Masonry for a project but i'm failry inexperienced with JS. I ran into an issue where hiding the first item in the Masonry grid caused the rest of the grid items to form into a single column.

I can hide and show as many other items as i want, just not the first one it seems.

The codepen below reproduces the problem, press "Create" to form the Masonry layout then "Hide" to hide the divs with class "special"...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByxmMv

Removing the class "special" from the first div will demonstrate the desired layout behavior.

I was hoping that i'm just doing something wrong but if i'm not can someone demonstrate a workaround?

Thanks of any help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Masonry</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function hide() {
      $(".special").hide();
      msnry.layout();
    }
    function show() {
      $(".special").show();
      msnry.layout();
    }
    function create() {
      container = document.querySelector('#container');
      msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        itemSelector: ".item",
        isAnimated: true
      });
    }
    function destroy() {
      msnry.destroy();
    }
  </script>


  <style type="text/css">
    #container {
      background: #EEE;
      max-width: 80%;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    .item {
      width:  150px;
      height: 150px;
      float: left;
      background: green;
      border: 2px solid #333;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    .item:nth-child(3n){
      height: 100px;
    }
    .special {
      background:orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <button onclick="create()">Create</button>
  <button onclick="destroy()">Destroy</button>
  <button onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
  <button onclick="show()">Show</button>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item special"></div>
    <div class="item special"></div>
    <div class="item special"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item special"></div>
    <div class="item special"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item special"></div>
    <div class="item delete"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item special"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a 'sizer' element to get the proper width:

```
        msnry = new Masonry( container, {
            itemSelector: ".item",
            columnWidth: '.sizer',
            isAnimated: true
        });
```

http://codepen.io/herihehe/full/ravYEL/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my project when first element was hidden using 'item-hidden' class from css files:

```
.item-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Masonry uses jQuery selector for selecting column width from element, so I just put to use element without 'item-hidden' class:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-item:not(.item-hidden)'
});
```

Comment: Adjusting my show/hide to use a class and adding 'columnWidth' like you suggested worked for me.

Comment: Or simpler (without the need to add a new class): columnWidth: '.grid-item:not([style*="display: none"])'

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the class 'item' from the elements you are hiding and then re-instantiate by calling destroy() and create() functions. Just add the class back when showing again.

```js
function hide() {
  $(".special").removeClass('item').hide();
  destroy();
  create();
}

function show() {
  $(".special").addClass('item').show();
  destroy();
  create();
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByxmMv

Comment: A clean workaround but you loose the transition effect.